# Extended Grapheme Cluster - Swift

Tags: swift, unicode

In extended Graphemen Cluster, Is it necessary to combine each cluster in increasing hexadecimal order?
I have 2 variables in Swift:

```
let precomposed: Character = "\u{D55C}"                  // 한
let decomposed:Character = "\u{1112}\u{1161}\u{11AB}"
```

Both are printing same value but when I change the order in decomposer, the value is different. Like, if I changed it like this:

```
let decomposed:Character = "\u{1161}\u{1112}\u{11AB}"
```

then it is showing me a error because it is treating it like String of separate cluster values

Comment: It is necessary to provide the codepoints or graphemes in the order dictated by the Unicode rules. What does this have to do with Swift?

Comment: @matt I have 2 variables in Swift:
let precomposed: Character = "\u{D55C}"                  // 한
let decomposed:Character = "\u{1112}\u{1161}\u{11AB}"
Both are printing same value but when I change the order in decomposer, the value is different. Like, if I changed it like this: 
let decomposed:Character = "\u{1161}\u{1112}\u{11AB}"
then it is showing me a error because it is treating it like String of separate cluster values

Comment: Very good. Then _put that in your question_. (And format it, please.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Swift. It's purely a Unicode matter. If you use the individual noncombining jamo, and you want them combined automatically, there are Unicode rules for the order (which is basically left-to-right order). See for example http://unicode.org/L2/L2009/09052-tr47.html, and the section "Hangul Syllable Composition" in https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/ch03.pdf.

Comment: So the order may in fact be increasing hexadecimal order, but in a way that's just a coincidence; the _actual_ required order is the written order of the jamo.

Comment: I am new in case of unicode. Can you explain in very simple words?